# imageresizer is not working with Azure CDN

Tags: .net, azure, azure-blob-storage, imageresizer, azure-cdn

We have a blob storage in Azure and we also have an azure CDN that points to this blob storage. How would we configure Imageresizer so that it can work with the CDN. Currently we have configured Imageresizer in web.config with the connectionstring of the blob storage, but don't know how to change this to work with the CDN because its work if I call https://example.com/image.png?width=100 but its not work with my CDN url https://exampleCDN.azureedge.net/image.png?width=100. Many thanks

Comment: Just based on URL conventions, shouldnt that be width=100

Comment: yes correct one